# how change values in NSdictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

How change value "level 1-2 closed" on "level 1-2 open"?
I have to delete it and add new value? or simply overwrite?
How can I do it?

Thanks

```
   NSDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"key_open_levels"];

         dict  = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    @"open", @"level 1-1",
                    @"closed", @"level 1-2",
                    @"closed", @"level 1-3",
                    @"closed", @"level 1-4",
                    @"closed", @"level 1-5",
                    @"closed", @"level 1-6",
                    @"closed", @"level 1-7",
                    @"closed", @"level 1-8",
                    @"closed", @"level 1-9",
                    @"closed", @"level 1-10", nil];

           // NSString *customerDict ;
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:dict forKey:@"key_open_levels"];


           if ([[dict valueForKey:@"level 1-2"] isEqualToString:@"closed" ]){

           //what should I write here?

           }else{

}
```

Comment: that isn't a mutable dictionary, so after its creation you can't change anything.

Comment: how? can you give example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try below code..

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dict  = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"open", @"level 1-1",
                        @"closed", @"level 1-2",
                        @"closed", @"level 1-3",
                        @"closed", @"level 1-4",
                        @"closed", @"level 1-5",
                        @"closed", @"level 1-6",
                        @"closed", @"level 1-7",
                        @"closed", @"level 1-8",
                        @"closed", @"level 1-9",
                        @"closed", @"level 1-10", nil];

[dict removeObjectForKey:@"level 1-2"];
[dict setObject:@"open" forKey:@"level 1-2"];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to add your entire `NSDictionary` to `NSMutableDictionary`

```
NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[newDict addEntriesFromDictionary: dict];
[newDict setObject:@"<value>" forKey:@"<Key Name>"];
NSLog(@"%@", newDict);
```

Answer (score 1):

NSDictionary is immutable so can't change the value. NSMutableDictionary is mutable then only you add,delete performes can be done.

use @Amar said link . it helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
In your code below  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:dict forKey:@"key_open_levels"];

Use below line of code than it will work.

[defaults synchronize];
```

Also use NSMutableDictionary instead of NSDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert `NSDictionary` to `NSMutableDictionary`.

Or

You have to user `NSMutableDictionary`  in place of the `NSDictionary`.

After that you can able to change value in `NSMutableDictionary`.

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [dict mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides us `NSMutableDictionary` and `NSDicitionary` to store data in key-value pair, in which `NSMutableDicitonary` is editable. It depends on the use that if the data will be alter you should use `NSMutableDictionary` instead of creating `NSDictionary` or `[instanceOfNSDictionary mutableCopy]`

For example:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict2  = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
         @"open", @"level 1-1",
         @"closed", @"level 1-2",
         @"closed", @"level 1-3",
         @"closed", @"level 1-4",
         @"closed", @"level 1-5",
         @"closed", @"level 1-6",
         @"closed", @"level 1-7",
         @"closed", @"level 1-8",
         @"closed", @"level 1-9",
         @"closed", @"level 1-10", nil];  

[dict2 setObject:@"open" forKey:@"level 1-2"]; //<---- Set value at later stage
```

**EDIT**

```
        // Archive data to save
        NSMutableArray *archiveArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSData *personEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:completeResponse];
        [archiveArray addObject:personEncodedObject];

        // Set in userDefault
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:archiveArray forKey:@"key_open_levels"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


        // Get archived data from userdefault
        archiveArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"key_open_levels"];

        // Unarchive and use it
        NSLog(@"%@", [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[archiveArray objectAtIndex:0]]);
```

Comment: and how use NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults for saving data?

Comment: completeResponse it is NSString? and it is empty?

Answer (score -1):

you can do like this.. nsdictionary is static. we can't set object once it is created. take it as a nsmutabledictionary . you can chage it.
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

```
dict  = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
         @"open", @"level 1-1",
         @"closed", @"level 1-2",
         @"closed", @"level 1-3",
         @"closed", @"level 1-4",
         @"closed", @"level 1-5",
         @"closed", @"level 1-6",
         @"closed", @"level 1-7",
         @"closed", @"level 1-8",
         @"closed", @"level 1-9",
         @"closed", @"level 1-10", nil];



[dict setObject:@"open" forKey:@"level 1-5"];

NSLog(@"%@",dict);
```